# Statsmodels Vector Autoregession - Plots Overalapping

Tags: matplotlib, statsmodels

I am using vector autoregression from statsmodels:
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/vector_ar.html

When I call `results.plot()`, my subplots are overlapping, can someone provide a solution?
[image: the annoying overlapping pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be too much data to fit nicely on a plot, but give this a try.

call the `results.plot()` into a figure and then call `.tight_layout()`

so:

```
...#other code to get your model fit
fig = results.plot()
fig.tight_layout()
fig
```

That should let `matplotlib` figure out the best way to make it all fit.